# Practical approaches to structured data extraction from plain text: Looking for ideas & feedback

Tags: nlp, text-mining, information-retrieval, unsupervised-learning, information-extraction

I am member of a Facebook group for local ride shares. The group is specific for two cities and everything that is in-between, so the post are (mostly) as such:

- *"I'm gonna drive from city A to city Z tomorrow afternoon"*
- *"Anybody wanna join from city Z -> city A tonight"*
- *"Tomorrow at 4 pm, I need to drive from city D to city Z"*

So I've been thinking about possible ways to build a simple search engine for it where people can select a date/time and the direction where they need to go. I'm thinking that in the end, I would like to have a structured tuple such as `{start: 'city A', end: 'city Z', time: '15/04/2020 14:00'}`. (I'd probably get the date from the post metadata.)

I'm not that advanced in NLP/text mining techniques that could make it in production, so I'm looking for some input on my ideas here:

#### Option a): A rule-based approach

- Use a common NLP library like StanfordNLP
- Build a classic pipeline with preprocessing (stop word removal, ...), POS tagging etc.
- Annotate all cities that we know about and define synonyms for abbreviations
- Create enough specific rules to cover most cases
- Probably a solid baseline, but as always: Edge cases would most likely be tedious

#### Option b): Supervised Learning

- Turn it into a classification problem with "City A -> Z" and "City Z -> A" being the classes
- Problem 1: Need for a hand-labeled dataset
- Problem 2: Sub-routes in-between city A and Z become difficult
- Not really my favorite option

#### Option c): Unsupervised Learning

- Use an Autoencoder to extract the useful information from the posts
- No need for hand-labeling data
- Ideally, the latent space representation would contain all the information I need

Option c) is my favorite and also the technically most interesting option, but I just started reading about this topic. Some thoughts I have about it:

- How would I point the Autoencoder towards the information I'm specifically interested in?
- I read that with variational Autoencoders, you can manually set the bottleneck "thin enough" so that the compressed code contains what you're looking for. Is this a trial-and-error process or is there any intuition behind it?
- Is an Autoencoder even the right choice to do structured data extraction from text?
- Do you see any alternative approaches that I might have missed?

I would really appreciate some thoughts, comments and paper or book recommendations. With all the current down time, I'm hoping to do some hands-on work on this and get some more experience in unsupervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is super cool! I think that option A will probably work fairly well if the posts are very formulaic, but it really isn't that exciting.

Option B, like you point out will need training data.

Option C, really isn't the right use case of an autoencoder to try to extract latent information and somehow get from unstructured data to structured classifications.

I'd like to throw my hat in the ring with option D, it combines some of all 3 (or at least B and C). I suggest using BERT (or some flavor of it, like RoBERTa) which pulls in some of option C, then throwing a simple classifier on top of it for prediction. Because we're using BERT we can make do with a very small dataset. A suggestion for classification, I would mask the location names (found using NER) and then do predictions. For example, "I'm going from LA to San Fran" (Spacy picks up both as GPE, I did some tests and it is actually surprisingly good at abbreviations) would become "I'm going from A to B", then have the prediction be A to B or B to A. This would reduce classes and allow multiple locations, if we had "A to B to C" it would be several classification problems: A to B, then B to C. You could then do the computation again, just changing masks (technically it requires n choose 4 computations, choosing the two highest activation, maybe throwing out reverses)

I would get the dataset by bootstrapping it using option A, or even better quickly entering it yourself (because we're using BERT it shouldn't require too much data).

As for paper recommendations, I'm just in love with BERT lately https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf. I'm really into political applications, so I thought TD Parse was awesome https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E17-1046.pdf. Tell me how this project goes!